# How can I provide ID for TextEdit and Button in xamarin StackLayout

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

How can I give ID for a `TextEdit` (email, password) and save `Button` in the below `StackLayout`. I have choosen `Cross Platform App(Xamarin.Forms or Native)` to build a simple xamarin app. Below is `MainPage.xaml`.I am looking to receive the email value in my `MainActivity.cs`.

```
<Entry Placeholder="Email Id"></Entry>
<Entry Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
```

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        EditText emailText;
        Button savebtn;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());


        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Well you seem to be confused with Xamarin Android and Xamarin Forms

Comment: This is my first attempt on Xamarin space, I am stuck now, could you give a hand

Comment: Sure, take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `x:Name` attribute to an element, so, in this case:

```
<Entry x:Name="emailEntry" Placeholder="Email Id"></Entry>
<Entry x:Name="passwordEntry" Placeholder="Password" IsPassword="True"></Entry>
```

Then, in your page code-behind class (`Page.xaml.cs`) you can access those elements like this:

```
var emailText = emailEntry.Text;
var passwordText = passwordEntry.Text;
```

Comment: Awesome  I will try and get back soon.